# Display only Companies that does not supply "Beverages" in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server

having trouble here with SQL statement for displaying companies that does not supply beverages. Now the problem here is that there are few companies that supply both beverage and other stuff. I need it to only display companies that does not supply beverages at all. When i run my modified SQL statement, i managed to get what i want but, for those companies that supply foods as well as beverages, it is still being displayed because of my WHERE clause i set to search for `C.CategoryName != 'Beverages'`. I just want to remove those companies that supply both beverages and foods so i can only display those companies that purely supply **only** foods.

Sorry if i have some grammer mistake or anything or my question is unclear. I just don't really know how to explain professionally as it is hard to describe my problem. Thanks for those who willing to help me, i am really appreciate it. And also i do not know if these info and source codes are sufficient regarding my problem. Will provide more info/source code if needed.

Pictures of Both Category & Products table.

**Category Table**
[image: dbo.Category]

**Products Table**
[image: dbo.Products]

Here's the Initial statement

```
SELECT P.ProductName
FROM Products AS P
INNER JOIN
Categories AS C
ON
C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
AND C.CategoryName = 'Beverages'
```

Result

[image: This only displayed all beverages from the 'products' table.]

So far here's the modified statement

```
SELECT S.CompanyName, P.CategoryID, C.CategoryID FROM Suppliers AS S
INNER JOIN
Products AS P
ON S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Categories AS C
ON
C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
AND C.CategoryName != 'Beverages'
```

Result

[image]

Comment: If you have a select that returns all companies and another select that returns companies that supply beverages you can then use `EXCEPT`

Comment: Thanks mate, really help me there.. i have been struggling with this for a few days until you came to the rescue.. really appreciate it man!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer Suggested by [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith).

With adding EXCEPT Clause to the SQL statement to my modified SQL statement, i managed to get it done. Here is the Answer to my problem.

```
SELECT S.CompanyName FROM Suppliers AS S
EXCEPT
SELECT S.CompanyName FROM Suppliers AS S
INNER JOIN
Products AS P
ON S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID
RIGHT JOIN
Categories AS C
ON
C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
AND C.CategoryName = 'Beverages'
```

Comment: Nice set based approach, but be aware that the EXCEPT statement in SQL Server is very computationally expensive, so only use it if your data-set will remain small and you don't mind it chewing up some resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH FOODSUPPLIERS AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT SUPPLIERID
    FROM PRODUCTS P
    JOIN CATEGORY C ON C.CATEGORYID = P.CATEGORYID
    WHERE CATEGORYNAME <> 'Beverages'
)
SELECT S.COMPANYNAME FROM SUPPLIERS S
JOIN FOODSUPPLIERS FS ON FS.SUPPLIERID = S.SUPPLIERID
```

The `FOODSUPPLIERS` CTE identifies suppliers in PRODUCTS that are not associated with any beverage products, i.e., associated only with food products.  It's then a simple matter of joining the CTE to Suppliers to get the records for these suppliers.